# Documentation for jsPDF that actually tells me the options I can set?

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf

I'm having trouble learning anything from the documentation, how am I supposed to know which options exists in for example the .html method? It only says I can add an options object, but doesn't say what those options can be. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a possible alternative to find out, you can follow a source link for particular method ([Documentation](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/jsPDF.html)) to see the code. In this case it's:

https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/modules_html.js.html#line749

This is what options object can be:

```
options = options || {};
options.callback = options.callback || function () {};
options.html2canvas = options.html2canvas || {};
options.html2canvas.canvas = options.html2canvas.canvas || 
this.canvas;
options.jsPDF = options.jsPDF || this;
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/modules_html.js.html) you can see the code behind the .html module:

```
/**
 * Generate a PDF from an HTML element or string using.
 *
 * @name html
 * @function
 * @param {Element|string} source The source element or HTML string.
 * @param {Object=} options An object of optional settings.
 * @description The Plugin needs html2canvas from niklasvh
 */
jsPDFAPI.html = function (src, options) {
    'use strict';

    options = options || {};
    options.callback = options.callback || function () {};
    options.html2canvas = options.html2canvas || {};
    options.html2canvas.canvas = options.html2canvas.canvas || this.canvas;
    options.jsPDF = options.jsPDF || this;
      // Create a new worker with the given options.

    var pdf = options.jsPDF;

    var worker = new Worker(options);
    if (!options.worker) {
    // If worker is not set to true, perform the traditional 'simple' operation.
        return worker.from(src).doCallback();
    } else {
    // Otherwise, return the worker for new Promise-based operation.
        return worker;
    }
    return this;
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

jsPDF.html [parameters](https://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-html.html#%7Ehtml:%7E:text=Parameters):

> Name  Type    Attributes  Description
>
> callback  function     The
> mandatory callback-function gets as first parameter the current jsPDF
> instance
>
> margin    number | Array.  Page margins [top, right,
> bottom, left]. Default is 0.
>
> autoPaging    boolean | 'slice' | 'text'   The auto paging mode.
>
> false: Auto paging is disabled. true or 'slice': Will cut shapes or
> text chunks across page breaks. Will possibly slice text in half,
> making it difficult to read. 'text': Trys not to cut text in half
> across page breaks. Works best for documents consisting mostly of a
> single column of text. Default is true. filename  string  
> name of the file
>
> image HTMLOptionImage  image settings when converting HTML
> to image
>
> html2canvas   Html2CanvasOptions   html2canvas options
>
> fontFaces Array.     A list of font-faces to match
> when resolving fonts. Fonts will be added to the PDF based on the
> specified URL. If omitted, the font match algorithm falls back to old
> algorithm.
>
> jsPDF jsPDF    jsPDF instance
>
> x number   x position on the PDF document in jsPDF units.
>
> y number   y position on the PDF document in jsPDF units.
>
> width number   The target width in the PDF document in jsPDF
> units. The rendered element will be scaled such that it fits into the
> specified width. Has no effect if either the html2canvas.scale is
> specified or the windowWidth option is NOT specified.
>
> windowWidth   number   The window width in CSS pixels. In
> contrast to the html2canvas.windowWidth option, this option affects
> the actual container size while rendering and does NOT affect CSS
> media queries. This option only has an effect, if the width option is
> also specified.